# Typescript generic depends on order of parameters, while it should not

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I have generic `mergeArrays` which does not depend on order of parameters.
But when used inside another generic it seems result depend. But it is not understandable.

```
type Fn = (...args: any[]) => any;

type arr1LessThanOrEqual<
  T1 extends ReadonlyArray<any>,
  T2 extends ReadonlyArray<any>
  > = T1["length"] extends T2["length"]
  ? true
  : T2["length"] extends 0
  ? false
  : T2 extends [infer First, ...infer Rest]
  ? Rest extends ReadonlyArray<any>
  ? arr1LessThanOrEqual<T1, Rest>
  : never
  : never;

type mergeArrWithLeft<
  T1 extends ReadonlyArray<any>,
  T2 extends ReadonlyArray<any>
  > = readonly [
    ...{
      readonly [Index in keyof T1]: Index extends keyof T2
      ? (T1[Index] & T2[Index])
      : T1[Index];
    }
  ];

type mergeArrays<
  T1 extends ReadonlyArray<any>,
  T2 extends ReadonlyArray<any>
  > = arr1LessThanOrEqual<T1, T2> extends true
  ? mergeArrWithLeft<T2, T1>
  : mergeArrWithLeft<T1, T2>;
```

and here i use this generic:

```
type LargestArgumentsList<T extends ReadonlyArray<any>> = T extends readonly [
  (...args: infer Args) => any,
  ...infer Rest
] ?
  mergeArrays<LargestArgumentsList<Rest>, Args> // here if I swap it does not work, but generic mergeArrays does not depend on order of params, so  it is a  mistery
  : readonly [];
```

and it works.
but if i swap it to:

```
type LargestArgumentsList<T extends ReadonlyArray<any>> = T extends readonly [
  (...args: infer Args) => any,
  ...infer Rest
] ?
  mergeArrays<Args, LargestArgumentsList<Rest>>
  : readonly [];
```

the behaviour of `LargestArgumentsList` is different, here is [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgdlAvFAFAOgwQwE4HMDOAXFJnCANoC6AlEgHwlkDcAsAFDuiQnbYCMAGQj58AFQAWpAPLYAogEcArpgA2AHnZQoovlAgAPYBDgATfFABKETCYD2cFSACCvTCDWkQdADSbtAJj1DYzNLazsHZ1d3Tzo-BmQdcgAiFWNcYHFkyiCjU3NRfxS0uAysyj8AfihgbEUIP2JC4vTM7NyQ8wAGKqgAM1V8BrYtJsCDPNDyAEs4PohsWGnsfGBvKAw0WfnFq1WKkahqveAO-LCbe0cXbDcPMjjD6px+IREJaTklVTUddZPHqMoHAIAA3BaNYFghasDhsAD08KgAHdxMYoCUynpvipzNNTsjpioVFBsMJFCpTtMALbUiAmaaYIyOGp1YYAY3sqx4r2EYkkcBkCmUKgA+qJhMA+MQXoI+R9BV8RWoqOsqAlWfV2IioNM+lAhpy4KYeRjWuIkIhkF0SLjbLrafTGcyQP1BhyuadZW9+Z9hapxZL-DLeHL3gKhTiVXAKSpKGrKBqBriPXBud75RGlQGJasAMwh3nhv1R1VQcgx4mJpCa1Pp0M+hWRkWB1YAFkLYd9iv96grsfWlZUg9j8fLQ5HxMnw+BA9nU-ncY1tS1cK40DpeAgNwA6vjxEI+sANIcdGdQlZLpEbndYr5T+NgudLxFrtF7l54jWyVeWeQ-FomwAN4AVopLhFcrrkAAkqYBi6ggADWEAgLY+o6JQxCwSY8ETJ0UDIah6H+KBWjVCgSTYQYOQAGQBDBcH6DQpFQE0fAMThTGwmBUAAL5+JQsKcOAG4LLg27RPgJ5aGeeHPhB17vnefiFOe5gvpBN4xA8X7IBmxY9lGfwBAwcmhCuwxkVAm7ibu+6HsehTrDogKsdZYkSdge6ZA5vx8M5-h0EJcI6gAEgs0DItAQzQJkTLuVuWnmHYwjArYpw4ZA5z2FAtjYDhixoVAYA4JgdJGCswncNSXS6MgNmeW4UlluqsI6lAAB6lTsFVG5dAArDWDVJdGijUgARgsY6tdqSKdd1bDrtZXSBPVHkjS1MYTVNQWzVoXU9YtInLXmQ3rZJKrTVtk3YCO23YImbVzQdR3VV0ACcZ2JRd-b3XdN3TY9e3zYdS01W2X22T9V1jTd-0LPDD27Qiz0LWDfCnWt323CAzXXQjs5-YTAMJsj7Uvb1y0AGyQ41uOjfdMOM2TqOg8dNUAOy0xt+MPWqvOI0DKP7Wj7N8DaWNQzjeOwwTvNMwDLMi2zb0ABzcz98v87Lt3E3LOtC+TovVXwEOS3TMtEwLet8+OBtKyDa5i3VCVS01DNwzbCv68zT3K07Jura7Fsez7JN21bOuCw7L3o4N5s81HNuC9rke+8DFOvRufA0wnmtJ9bWsR57hf237juU9SfBc3n0uh7rpeM6nJcF63act+3O3l7HYvq7X7u-R3Q9hyPDdt+Hg+j9H3cLewRrcuyaLsohACytXEDVLtULC8+nIvEDL2vwbLUH5B8IJc+elA++H10BYnTWZ-rP4F9sLv19L6vXQdstZvlv5UB-DrDzK-d+N8v79Q3gNR+58d5X3AWvKmUDc7-1AfAz+a8OZQJrv-Z+aC0x7wwV0VWUC+64MAcA-BC8MF8HelAz6yAn6AKoYQg+q9xYb3FjAvBcCCEfzYSvPg0prJCO4cw3h1CBF8GPlXU+ACgFQBARI1hh8MacMxuQhRSjL58IQabThf8mFaJYfw1RkCRHx00ZQ5Rpj2FIJESgox1idGSNUVgkROCnGKPWG2dY-V1hU3WBzExeiSEeLEVonxfiAlBNfpTAQOBxKrBcLgMaxhgD4AENMVYvw1IXFfFEHGH46AalEHkn8BTyx+HQFgPARAEI7CgCk-AtBEAME8PeQCGBtgLDCKsdgOQFpaGGhdBJW5kl4DSXADJWSckAnWM0hgOo0Rkl1PqaCBpkSYDALqDKthUpwHSiiPKiF1jjUUKccSIJsDTHZMHJKUAUrmEORlCAWUTC5QQHlAquV9QlVuNSfA6x8D2l2bqcwmBhnZIqiASEFTILljiW-K+NgTAuxQJgYgvNWntJcV6EwHzkAYqxUncaJL7o4tQJCgA1FAca1A8UkAJRo4lyc6Xks9uyDlCxKUYqgLS8a-Lr4MoDtAFQ0KugSygGMpJwAUlTJmdCtQ8LIjlnXEVVFIDkaU3FasWqNYZWSnlXSaZmSlUqr-Oq-UqL1hWqZSYLVsIlq6uACtA1iSjWTJNYqnJFqoJ2s1bakSGqCVC2dRKjRhqJmpO9Wa31ClLXButcyoNkAQ0mFTRAdNQsdUSr-lGuVXr0lxuPH6tVSb7V5kzem6tyaM01ArTahtaa621vtWG46LroHIALca4tszS0Jv9Y2glbbA3Nqza2idNbp1ToDaG5G4a9UoN7UW01A7lVDvLS2+1Y7R2zsrXu+t87j0jpMB27gXacGrpjf281W7yAnqPc+g946n2voXU6ztEqyE3oVSWzdv5h07qbe+sDZ6j1Vo-eexd369UMOlR66N-6N1lsfRB6DL7wMgf3Sex1h0wGfwHevDEEqt7yOcci3RRGJXHy7XI5+lHCNsOI-fLtGivHaLhMx5exGf5dsMRRxRISaN6vMV2yxnGRMsYlfYrtjihNcZ44hYj7ir0RKY+gmTeqwldrIVJmx4DiN0NI-BjTwngrsCAA)

I tried to create a generic which finds the longest list of arguments in array of function.
And i expect `mergeArrays` generic to not depend on order of parameters. I tested and it does not depend on order of parameters. But inside another generic(`LargestArgumentsList`) it works differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of `arr1LessThanOrEqual` is missing a `readonly` in the `T2 extends [infer First, ...infer Rest]` constraint. Since `Args` is not readonly, `arr1LessThanOrEqual` works when `Args` is the second parameter, but if you swap it with the readonly `LargestArgumentsList<Rest>`, it will fail.

If you replace the constraint with

```
T2 extends readonly [infer First, ...infer Rest]
```

`LargestArgumentsList` will work even when the parameters are swapped.

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgdlAvFAFAOgwQwE4HMDOAXFJnCANoC6AlEgHwlkDcAsAFDuiQnbYCMAGQj58AFQAWpAPLYAogEcArpgA2AHnZQoovlAgAPYBDgATfFABKETCYD2cFSACCvTCDWkQdADSbtAJj1DYzNLazsHZ1d3Tzo-BmQdcgAiFWNcYHFkyiCjU3NRfxS0uAysyj8AfihgbEUIP2JC4vTM7NyQ8wAGKqgAM1V8BrYtJsCDPNDscPtHKHIASzg%20iGxYBex8YG8oDDQllbWrLYqRqGrj4A78sJtZqOw3DzI4s%20qcfiERCWk5JVU1DodpdXqMoHAIAA3VaNcFQ1asDhsAD0yKgAHdxMYoCUynp-ipzAsruiFioVFBpvhFCorgsALb0iAmBaYIxzWr1dgAY3sWx4n2EYkkcBkCmUKgA%20qJhMA%20MQPoIhT9RX8JWoqDsqAkanVhqioAs%20lAhry4KYBTjWuIkIhkF0SITbIbGczWeyQP1BsMzfzFV9hb9xappbL-AreErviKxQSNXAaSpKFrKDqBoSfXyrv7lTG1SGZVsAMwRwXRoNxzXzBPk1NIXVcti%207ORgMq2MS0NbAAspajgdVwfU5BrKh2o-HieT1cTk-Jc7H4NnS-nK6TOs5w044GgTLwEBc2AA6sTxEI%20sANGcdNdQlY7pFD09Yr5r%20Ngjd7xFHE%20Yi94vW0wPnM5B%20FoewAN5gVolIzJE8wAJKmAYhoIAA1hAIC2MaOiUMQSEmChEydFAGFYTh-jQVo1QoEkBEGDkABkATkPR%20g0FRUBNHwrHIexiIwVAAC%20fiUIi27cHuuAHtE%20BXloN7EZ%20cE-tEzxeK%20CnvpM5hfvcv7qaCUA6jm5aDnGQIBAwSmhJuvRSTJx6nuel6FDsOhGcQDmHiemQuYCfDuf4dDiUiBoABKrNA6LQEM0CZGyUDebJUB2MI4K2FchGQDc9hQLY2CEWs2FQGAOCYEyRibBJu5dLoyDJY8IByVW2qIgaUAAHqVOwNVJV0ACs9aNW4LUJvSABGqzTm17Add1fX0l0gQNas0m-i1M3jVN2Cpu1aJdT1SJcLVRbDWtjmjRqW2KJNqyTndu0hXNB0LWwJ39QAnOd%204bfGt07Q9O0zXtL1aG9i1dN2P3rbJ11att91Lo9QPTc9KKvUdH30nwZ2rb9cMjgDSOI9gqO7Sm6PzUdkMAGww5dzX-Y9N0s1TmO9e9O79QA7Azf1EyzCPE2TyPA%20z4NY9zOMOvjsNNWNIvk6z4v7ZLnPY10AAc-OE6TKsk0rYto2rh2LXw0Ny4ziso8bov68LbOmxDXOSXw9VJRdAuk8rjuA3boMY%20rx3S3wK2ewTCvM-7DszrbPsBxLZuu7ufBDVb3tGwnseCzHIuB9TGuh-TGd61n5dC3Hefx-nScu9jfB86XUe54bNeV639sV9XPdt73T3O1Lbs683V2d%20TE925P2f537ffzwPYPJzyWZQNyWLcmhACydVeXV9ZUIizZrxv2-LXv4fkHwYkr3A-LrxAm87yW-V4-MgVQP4N9NqvD9P1De9Lbvx2P4HYRZv7Hz-mfAae907vwgb-U%20O9aZ7xLvAo%20iDH5nx5nvJuwDP4ILvlcKBO8tZ7xHvg0BUBwEYKISfLBW8%20CfT3t9ZAV8QGEPvkgvgXQvI8IPh-L%20tCuEMPdnwj27CCHCOIdw8MSUw4CJAWAzhMjREvxxm-SRVCaG3xEU-C2fCgFaOUdI%20h%20iYHyLgcY6hKizHbz4Cg%20RaDrE6J-nQkhjc%20F4JcTsbsOwBo7FpjsHmtiPFkPkd4wRYDfH%20MCcE7%20fUBA4GklsFwuBbrGGAPgAQCwtiAlvLpFSDxnwvB1KIApsFgKelAmcdAWA8BEFQocKAaT8C0EQAwTwmldgYAOKsMIWx2A5COloA0I0mZJP3KkvAGS4BZJyXkkEOxWlGXGXJVpOxJkpOAGk2Z8zcmXhBJ5Sp35qkJLcX6EwJgPYoEwMQUm7TOm6OzFc%20stz7lGwmh8x6jzUCYCgAAaigBNagzySBXLfu8qewLvn%2025LC1YvzbmAuBSi7koKQ7cBUAcrossoBbNlLspkczskHLUEBU58wTolRsCYcB6M%20rYq2PvZABLpnpOJfsvJFL7hUp3DSq5OxqXGlpfSxEH0mXAGWvWNlOyZmctJdyopfLIACrpUK-lIqrmBwlTit%20sqiWZMVZeHl8FyDCvBeqmomrLUatVVqkwgdGU4qAQa%20VRqFkmuVeam1oq7UQDVf6wN1r7W2pDQGh1QaHU6u5pKwaMrkmEvdSSz15LvUWtpVGy1RYs2ZvDcGjNgr83RvRrq5laC3Uco9WS01IFC0mFzUW%20tObi1hvrY2x1pbY04rwZWvZxq01VJVRGttvqm1joba2v1U7x2htpTGrFOKKF9oVam2t1T20zsnZundE6W31oXdAONrD8WJvZf2td6aJ0dpvVu29zanUXNUZvT1u8cQ4okVEmxpioGvrkXGy%20X7XGQNPq%20l%20cbNFAfOSBrBr7ezvuZUYqDP7QM4osXGqxyGwW-pxY4uNzisNPrsa%20nBCGpWRKUd%207DqHmXhLjRQlxoSaNSuYWRroJ7GOhXYEAA)